# How can I initialize class variables in a header?

Tags: c++, class, variables, linker, initialization

I'm writing a library where the user can define arbitrary structures and pass them to my library, which will then obtain the memory layout of the structure from a static member such structure must have as a convention.

For example:

```
struct CubeVertex {
  // This is, per convention, required in each structure to describe itself
  static const VertexElement Elements[];

  float x, y, z;
  float u, v;
};

const VertexElement CubeVertex::Elements[] = {
  VertexElement("Position", VertexElementType::Float3),
  VertexElement("TextureCoordinates", VertexElementType::Float2),
};
```

C++ best practices would suggest that I move the static variable and its initialization into my source (.cpp) file. I, however, want to keep the variable initialization as close to the structure as possible since whenever the structure changes, the variable has to be updated as well.

Is there a portable (*= MSVC + GCC at least*) way to declare such a variable inside the header file without causing ambiguous symbol / redefinition errors from the linker?

Comment: Remark: Just as a consideration, moving the `CubeVertex::Elements` array into a source file would also make it impossible to figure out the size of the array via sizeof(), thus forcing another intermediate class upon the user or requiring a special terminator `VertexElement`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a simple getter.

```
struct CubeVertex {
    static const std::array<VertexElement, N>& GetElements() {
         static const std::array<VertexElement, N> result = {
             //..
         };
         return result;
    }
    //..
}
```

Immediate benefit: No array-to-pointer-decay.

Comment: That is brilliant! It even allows me to place a `using namespace` for the `VertexElement` class inside the getter method to shorten things without causing everyone using the header to involuntarily import that namespace. Since my library is targeting C++11 anyway, there's nothing in the way of using `std::array`, too. Thanks!

Comment: Tested in Visual C++ 2012 RC and with GCC 4.7.1 - working perfectly. Real world code: http://pastebin.com/XX4gdyEE :)

Answer (score 3):

What you could do here is using an anonymous namespace.

Wrap everything into "namespace { ... };" and you can then access CubeVertex::Elements like you normally do.

However, this creates a new instance of the static data everytime you include the headerfile, which adds to the executable's filesize.

It also has some limitations on how to use the class/struct, because you cannot call functions of that class from another file (which won't be a problem in this special case here).

Comment: +1 for an interesting idea. Of course I don't know what else the user of my library will be doing with his vertices and it's not unlikely that they will be passed from method to method across many compilation units.

Comment: *you cannot call functions of that class from another file* - there is no `class` inside the anonymous `namespace`, so no problem here

Comment: Assume a C++ project consuming my library had two header/source file pairs: `CubeBuilder.h/.cpp` and `CubeRenderer.h/.cpp`. When `CubeBuilder.cpp` is compiled, any references to `CubeVertex` in its header will be pointing to a completely different class than when `CubeRenderer.cpp` is compiled and includes the headers. The compiler won't complain, but the linker will see mismatching methods.